# Python2.7 PyGame set_mode issue and crash on script termination

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I've got an issue with Python2.7 and PyGame. It has only just started happening so not sure what's going on.

I've been coding a simple platform game and upon running the script it would immediately print out "160 20" (without quotes) and then start the PyGame script. On exiting the script using the "esc" key it crashed and a "python.exe has stopped working" dialog box appeared. I've also noticed that to exit the script while it's running I have to press "ctrl-c" twice as though there are two scripts running.

The funny thing is that this only seems to happen if set_mode is called in the script.

Another problem started when I decided to mess about with fullscreen. I used "DS = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H), FULLSCREEN|HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF)" and was able to get the game into fullscreen, now however any script I run with set_mode in automatically goes into fullscreen regardless of the parameters.

Totally bizarre!

Any thoughts?

PS. I tried uninstalling both PyGame and Python and then re-installing.

Ant

Answer (score 0):

Strange!

I've fixed the issue by giving my platform game script a new name and deleting the *.pyc file that was generated.

Good now I can get on with making the game!

Ant

Comment: maybe your name collided with name of some module so you was importing your file instead of expected module - it is very popular mistake.

Comment: The name of the file was platform.py so I guess that is completely possible.